# Linux - cleanup: find large groups of files by similar filenames

Tags: pattern-matching, filenames

**Question:**
on a Linux File System, I am trying to locate large numbers of files with similar name patterns; for cleanup. The issue here is that I have no idea what such patterns would look like; this is what the script should show us.

**Example:**
e.g., a typical outcome of the script could be:
"we have accumulated around 10k files looking like 'create_some_kind_of_log_*.log'
and 19k files matching '/some_kind_of_dir/daily_blah_file*.dat'"

Before we would not be 'aware' that these files are being accumulated in such large numbers; they were under the radar because of their small size.

Any input would be appreciated!

Cheers

**Edit**
Maybe a workaround would be to just look for directories where there are a large number of files; this could also help in the analysis.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I've modified the answer in case it is of use. This will produce a list of directories ranked by the number of files each holds.

```
find . -type d | xargs ls -dl | awk '{print $2, $9}' > f.tmp
sort -nr f.tmp
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for the answer. I am aware of find. The problem here is that we have no idea what the patterns will look like. So we need to just have some sort of algorithm to find any name pattern for which many files have a match (and e.g. longer than 5 chars or so)

Comment: That's an interesting problem. What about listing directories and sorting them to find the ones with the largest numbers of files? It should yield some interesting patterns.